# How to use aspx:dropdown with datasource in a form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I am working on a Asp.net project, where i need to fill a form with two two fields. Let's say

```
<form>
 a_text <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server"/>

        <asp:CheckBox ID="TestCheckboxes" runat="server" CssClass="tb_sm" />

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"  
            CssClass="ddlb" Width="210px" Height="30px"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
            DataTextField="OrderPeriod" DataValueField="OrderPeriodID">
        </asp:DropDownList>

       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$  ConnectionStrings:ProdDB %>" SelectCommand=" # Some Command">
     </asp:SqlDataSource>

     <asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmit" runat="server" Text="Done" />
</form>
```

When i am selecting some value from database it refresh the page even there is no `OnSelectedIndexChanged` in dropdown list.

I am newbie in `asp.net`. How should i fill a form. How i get the value of the following method associated with submit button:

Comment: Check this `AutoPostBack="True"`, which will postback on selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 hello you hgave error on DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"

-> `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"`

You must select good SqlDataSource

try with this code

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            CssClass="ddlb" Width="210px" Height="30px"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
            DataTextField="OrderPeriod" DataValueField="OrderPeriodID">
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$  ConnectionStrings:ProdDB %>" SelectCommand=" # Some Command">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

2 You can get the value with

```
DropDownList1.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear up the first part of your query; it refreshes the page beacause you have `AutoPostBack` set to true on your `dropdownlist`